# PHP/JQUERY Selectbox chained

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a script the first selectbox works fine and should make the 2nd selectbox fill up further although that is never happening for some reason.

I have no clue why it is not putting the 2nd selectbox right. I know the query both boxes work since the 1st box works although when u select the number 2nd box is empty

Could someone please assist me?

**jQuery/CSS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.country').change(function() {
         var id = $(this).val();
         var dataString = 'id=' + id;

         $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'box2.php',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
               $('.city').html(html);
            } 
         });
      });
   });
</script>

<style>
   label {
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 10px;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<label>Klantvraag:</label>
<select name="country" class="country">
   <option selected="selected">Kies uit lijst</option>
<?php 
   include 'config/instellingen.php';

   $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Klantvraag FROM `DWA` WHERE `Status DWA` = \'DBAA\' AND `Kenmerk` <> \'\'';

   if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
      while ($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo '<option value="' . $get['Klantvraag'] . '">' . $get['Klantvraag'] . '</option>';
      }
   }
?>
</select> <br/><br/>
<label>Contract nr.:</label>
<select name="city" class="city">
   <option selected="selected">Kies uit lijst</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
   if ($_POST['id']) {
      $id = $_POST['id'];

      include 'config/instellingen.php';

      $query = 'SELECT `Contract nr.` FROM `DWA` WHERE `Klantvraag` = \'1258819\'';

      if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
         while ($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $get['Contract nr.'] . '">' . $get['Contract nr.'] . '</option>';
         }
      }
   }
// ^ missing bracket right here
?>
```

Comment: Your last `if` clause was missing one bracket `}` which I added at the end. Could that have been the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last `if` construct is missing its ending bracket `}`.

Answer (score 0):

you selector is using class name `country` which only matches your first select box.

```
$(".country").change(function()
```

please adjust the selector or the class name or place a different selector for the second select box.

Comment: The second select box is `.city`... `<select name="city" class="city">`

Comment: I dont really understand what to change I have no experience in jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is your query is not dynamic since your where query always searchs for that particular id

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
include("config/instellingen.php");
$query = "SELECT `Contract nr.` FROM `DWA` WHERE `Klantvraag` = '1258819'";
                                                          //----^^^^^^^^--here..
```

i think it should be

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
include("config/instellingen.php");
$query = "SELECT `Contract nr.` FROM `DWA` WHERE `Klantvraag` = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: No I did that to be sure it would select SOMETHING but for somehow your code wont work either.

Comment: so you are sure this returns the options values??

Comment: The query works 100% but for somehow doesnt show up on the page lol

Comment: ok cool.. then check you console tab.. inside developers tool... if the ajax is giving you error then it should be there.... and make sure the path `box2.php` is correct

Comment: I have no experience in Ajax how do I do this :(?

Comment: if you are using chrome ..press f12 , this should open a developers tool , go to console tab... now if you change the country select..if there is error that should display in the console tab

Comment: Accepted also I have a second question. $query = 'SELECT Contract nr. FROM DWA WHERE Klantvraag = '$id''; when using $id the second field stopped working any idea why?